# Trimming spaces in a field logstash

Tags: logstash

After using a grok to map the fields some fields look like
`"                             DOG"`
So I was trying to trim the spaces before and after the word. I tried

```
fv{
   source => "Animal"
   trim_value => "\s"
   }
```

But it seems like nothing is happening. I also tried `trim_value => " "` I would like the field to be `"Dog"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you should use the [gsub](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub) option of the mutate filter.

```
mutate {
    gsub => [
      "Animal", "\s", ""
    ]
}
```

It would replace all spaces by an empty string, thereby removing them.

Comment: Thanks, I take it this wont work if it is 2 words like "Brown Dog"?

Comment: It removes all spaces. So "  Brown Dog  " becomes "BrownDog"